# find the length of smallest unique sub strings given 1000 of strings of length 100

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash, substring

Given 1000 strings of length 100 characters. The task is to compute the length of minimal sub string for every string, which is unique among all the sub strings generated by the 1000 strings.

## My Approach

1. generate all the sub strings of length 1-100, for every string and store it in the map,and keep increasing the count if duplicate sub string is found.
2. Regenerate all the sub strings for every string starting from length 1, if the count of any of sub string of length L is one, output L.

## Observation

1. This solution gets TLE in C++, and passes in java. My understanding for the same is, stl::map operations done in log(N) time whereas HashMap operation is accomplished in O(1).

## Problem

- I am thinking for a solution, implementing my own hashes.The problem I am facing is 1) to choose, the appropriate value for the size of Hash Array 2) How do I generate the hash from the given strings so collision can be avoided at most.

Any other optimal approach for the above problem is appreciable.

Comment: `std::unordered_map`? Write a quick `string_view` type class to avoid all the memory duplication? Use a `trie`?

Comment: @Yakk: the support of c++ 11 is not avail in the target platform.I thought about Trie, but knowing the facts that operations in the Trie takes  O(log N) and map in C++ is implemented using RBTree, I don't find any advantage using it. Could u please explain how string_view can be implemented to avoid duplicates.

Comment: A `container_view` is a pair of iterators into some other container, marking the begin/end that this view has into that other container.  A `string_view` is a pair of iterators (probably pointers) into a string (probably `std::string`), allowing you to work with substrings without making a new copy of the characters in that substring.  Unlike C strings and `std::string`, a `string_view` isn't null terminated, but instead ends where the `end` iterator of the view points.  `strncmp` together with `size` comparisons lets you implement `operator<` pretty easily.  Stuff views in `std::map` and see.

Comment: There are O(N^2) substrings of length 1 to N.  A std::map with be O(log n) where n is the number of strings.  A trie will be O(n) where n is the length of the longest substring.

Comment: @ brian beuning: got your explanation, I have checked the Trie based solution, its working here :). I believe hashing also help me to crack this type of problem, lets me digg it more.

Comment: Actually, this problem can be solved in `O(N*L*log(N*L))` time using a Suffix Array, where `N = 1000, L = 100` in your case.

Comment: @fuch:I am agree with you. Suffix Array provide best complexity when the search Area is large. We can precompute the Array and answer instantly. I am interested to find out a solution based on hashing too.

Comment: @rspr Could you post a link to the problem? I want to try my hash.

Comment: @pkacprzak:the problem link is available at intranet, not accessible from outside.

Comment: You can #include<tr1/unordered_map> and use std::tr1::unordered_map. Or you can implement your own hashtable. Use some trivial hashing functions as DJBX33A and use chaining for handling collisions. You might want to store indices to start and end of substring instead of the string (saves memory).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array of char*, each element is pointer to each symbol in the your strings. For your problem, array size is 100x1000 = 100000 char* pointers. O(N)
2. Sort this array as "strings in alphabet order". O(N*Log(N))
3. Scan strings, and for each [i]-th string search max_eq_prefix 
   between this string and strings [i+1] and [i-1]. 
   For first and last strings run single comparisons, with [i+1] 
   for first, and [i-1] for last. O(N)

String with minimal max_eq_prefix is your substring, 
length is length(max_eq_prefix) + 1.

Example to figure out max_eq_prefix:

```
i-1:aabala
i:  aabumba
i+1:acron
```

For string [i], max_eq_prefix is aab. So, unique substring is "aabu".

As you see, this is kind of minimax algorithm.